# Script writes partial content to a csv file

Tags: php, csv, curl, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I've written a script in `php` to scrape the `titles` and its `links` from a webpage and write them accordingly to a csv file. As I'm dealing with a paginated site, only the content of last page remains in the csv file and the rest are being overwritten. I tried with writing mode `w`. However, when I do the same using append `a` then I find all the data in that csv file.

As `appending` and `writing` data makes the csv file open and close multiple times (because of my perhaps wrongly applied loops), the script becomes less efficient and time consuming.

How can i do the same in an efficient manner and of course using (writing) `w` mode?

This is I've written so far:

```
<?php
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$link = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?page="; 

function get_content($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $htmlContent = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $dom = new simple_html_dom();
        $dom->load($htmlContent);
        $infile = fopen("itemfile.csv","a");
        foreach($dom->find('.question-summary') as $file){
            $itemTitle = $file->find('.question-hyperlink', 0)->innertext;
            $itemLink = $file->find('.question-hyperlink', 0)->href;
            echo "{$itemTitle},{$itemLink}<br>";
            fputcsv($infile,[$itemTitle,$itemLink]);
        }
        fclose($infile);
    }
for($i = 1; $i<10; $i++){
        get_content($link.$i);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to open and close the file multiple times, then move the opening script before your `for`-loop and close it after:

```
function get_content($url, $inifile)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $htmlContent = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $dom = new simple_html_dom();
    $dom->load($htmlContent);
    foreach($dom->find('.question-summary') as $file){
        $itemTitle = $file->find('.question-hyperlink', 0)->innertext;
        $itemLink = $file->find('.question-hyperlink', 0)->href;
        echo "{$itemTitle},{$itemLink}<br>";
        fputcsv($infile,[$itemTitle,$itemLink]);
    }
}

$infile = fopen("itemfile.csv","w");

for($i = 1; $i<10; $i++) {
    get_content($link.$i, $inifile);
}

fclose($infile);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider not echoing or writing results to the file in `get_content` function. I would rewrite it so it would only *get* content, so I can handle extracted data any way I like. Something like this (please read code comments):

```
<?php
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$link = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?page="; 

// This function does not write data to a file or print it. It only extracts data
// and returns it as an array.
function get_content($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $htmlContent = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $dom = new simple_html_dom();
        $dom->load($htmlContent);
        // We don't need the following line anymore
        // $infile = fopen("itemfile.csv","a");
        // We will collect extracted data in an array
        $result = [];
        foreach($dom->find('.question-summary') as $file){
            $itemTitle = $file->find('.question-hyperlink', 0)->innertext;
            $itemLink = $file->find('.question-hyperlink', 0)->href;
            $result []= [$itemTitle, $itemLink];
            // echo "{$itemTitle},{$itemLink}<br>";
            // No need to write to file, so we don't need the following as well
            // fputcsv($infile,[$itemTitle,$itemLink]);
        }
        // No files opened, so the following line is no more required
        // fclose($infile);
        // Return extracted data from this specific URL
        return $result;
    }
// Merge all results (result for each url with different page parameter
// With a little refactoring, get_content() can handle this as well
$result = [];
for($page = 1; $page < 10; $page++){
    $result = array_merge($result, get_content($link.$page));
}
// Now do whatever you want with $result. Like writing its values to a file, or print it, etc.
// You might want to write a function for this
$outputFile = fopen("itemfile.csv","a");
foreach ($result as $row) {
    fputcsv($outputFile, $row);
}
fclose($outputFile);

?>
```

Comment: Sorry @Nima, for my belated response. Your script works like magic. Provided a plus. I need to study your code as this approach is slightly different from how I went about. Thanks a lot.